# Animation and Hiding the Bottom Scroll Bar

Tags: scrollbar, css-animations

I am working on a site where I have a left slide in animation. When it activates the scroll bar appears on the bottom and makes the page jump up and down a little. Is there anyway to make the scroll bar go away or change my animation code to stop it?

Chrome & IE are okay but Firefox is the jumpy one.

The site is: http://inventivewebdesign.com/ndr/

**HTML**

```
 <div id="ftr-tagline">
    <div class="slideLeft" id="ftr1-animation">
        <div class="one-third first">
            <div class="one-call">
                One Call...
            </div><!-- .one-call -->
        </div><!-- .one-third -->
    </div><!-- #ftr1-animation -->
    <div class="slideLeft" id="ftr2-animation">
        <div class="one-third">
            <div class="one-contact">
                One Contact...
            </div><!-- .one-contact -->
        </div><!-- .one-third -->
    </div><!-- #ftr2-animation -->
    <div class="slideLeft" id="ftr3-animation">
        <div class="one-third last">
            <div class="one-culture">
                One Culture...
            </div> <!-- .one-contact -->
        </div><!-- .one-third -->
    </div> <!-- #ftr3-animation -->
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
/*
==============================================
slideLeft
==============================================
*/


.page-id-4 #ftr1-animation, .page-id-4 #ftr2-animation, .page-id-4 #ftr3-animation{
    visibility: hidden;
}
.page-id-4 .slideLeft{
    animation-name: slideLeft;
    -webkit-animation-name: slideLeft;  

    animation-duration: 1s; 
    -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;

    animation-timing-function: ease-in-out; 
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;     

     /* Keep animation visible after animation finishes */
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards; 
}

@keyframes slideLeft {
    0% {transform: translateX(150%);}
    100% {transform: translateX(0%);
    visibility: visible;}
}

@-webkit-keyframes slideLeft {
    0% {-webkit-transform: translateX(150%);}   
    100% {-webkit-transform: translateX(0%);
    visibility: visible;}
}


.page-id-4 #ftr1-animation{
    -webkit-animation-delay: 2s; /* Safari and Chrome */
    animation-delay: 2s;
}
.page-id-4 #ftr2-animation{
    -webkit-animation-delay: 3s; /* Safari and Chrome */
    animation-delay: 3s;
}
.page-id-4 #ftr3-animation{
    -webkit-animation-delay: 4s; /* Safari and Chrome */
    animation-delay: 4s;    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to hide the overflow on the parent of the elements that are sliding in.

As in:

```
#ftr-tagline{
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Or if you can get away with it:

```
html, body{
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```